# Constants in Haxe

Tags: haxe

How do you create public constants in Haxe? I just need the analog of good old `const` in AS3:

```
public class Hello
{
     public static const HEY:String = "hey";
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The usual way to declare a constant in Haxe is using the `static` and  `inline` modifiers.

```
class Main {
    public static inline var Constant = 1;

    static function main() {
        trace(Constant);
        trace(Test.Constant);
    }
}
```

If you have a group of related constants, it can often make sense to use an [`enum abstract`](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-enum.html). Values of enum abstracts are `static` and `inline` implicitly.

---

Note that only the basic types (`Int`, `Float`, `Bool`) as well as `String` are allowed to be `inline`, for others it will fail with this error:

> Inline variable initialization must be a constant value

Luckily, Haxe 4 has introduced a `final` keyword which can be useful for such cases:

```
public static final Regex = ~/regex/;
```

However, `final` only prevents *reassignment*, it doesn't make the type immutable. So it would still be possible to add or remove values from something like `static final Values = [1, 2, 3];`.

For the specific case of arrays, Haxe 4 introduces [`haxe.ds.ReadOnlyArray`](https://api.haxe.org/v/development/haxe/ds/ReadOnlyArray.html?) which allows for "constant" lists (assuming you don't work around it using casts or reflection):

```
public static final Values:haxe.ds.ReadOnlyArray<Int> = [1, 2, 3];
```

```
Values = []; // Cannot access field or identifier Values for writing
Values.push(0); // haxe.ds.ReadOnlyArray<Int> has no field push
```

Even though this is an array-specific solution, the same approach can be applied to other types as well. `ReadOnlyArray<T>` is simply an [abstract type](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract.html) that creates a read-only "view" by doing the following:

- it wraps `Array<T>`
- it uses [`@:forward`](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-forward.html) to only expose fields that don't mutate the array, such as `length` and `map()`
- it allows [implicit casts](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-implicit-casts.html) `from Array<T>`

You can see how it's implemented [here](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/haxe/ds/ReadOnlyArray.hx).

Answer (score 9):

For non-static variables and objects, you can give them shallow constness as shown below:

```
public var MAX_COUNT(default, never):Int = 100;
```

This means you can read the value in the 'default' way but can 'never' write to it.

More info can be found http://adireddy.github.io/haxe/keywords/never-inline-keywords.