# Local constants in Haxe - possible

Tags: haxe

I know there is this question [Constants in Haxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424247/constants-in-haxe/25424433#25424433) about class properties. My question is: is it possible to define constants inside functions? Like:

```
function foo(){
   const bar=7;
   bar = 8; // should prevent compilation
}
```

Maybe anything like var `var foo:ReadOnlyInt` or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `final`.

```
function foo() {
   final bar = 7;
   bar = 8; // not allowed
}
```

https://haxe.org/manual/expression-var.html